# n_jobs in sklearn LinearRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I receive an error when I pass the n_jobs variable to the LinearRegression in sklearn.

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) it should support the n_jobs variable.

Am I making any mistake?

```
>>> sk.__version__
'0.16-git'
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
>>> LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, n_jobs=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'
>>> LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True)
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)
>>>
```

Comment: I have solved with an upgrade `sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git --upgrade`

Comment: Yes, this is a [relatively recent change](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/dc3b00dfc082f68efc1af0db8ae3ed0c1e5a874b)

Comment: worked for me on sklearn 0.15 and 0.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a new feature in scikit-learn, you need to update your package:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```